# How can this bar be done in iOS?

Tags: ios, popup

I really like this popup with the additional functions for the selected listitem under:

[image]

But have no idea how this is done. Does anyone know how to do it or has a guide or some keywords for me?

Here is another example:

[image]

Comment: Your second example does not obviously cover the very same issue. Maybe you can refine your question by describing what you try to achieve.

Comment: Till. you are completely right. I added a new question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve a similar effect by adding a UISegmentedControl with <1 alpha to the view when a cell is selected - hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The keywords to look out for are:

`UIToolBar` or `UISegmentedControl` - both using some custom drawing or appearance modifications. Well, you could just as well create an entire custom `UIView` containing a bunch of `UIImageView`'s.

Additionaly, for that shadow have a look at `CALayer`'s `shadowOffset`, `shadowColor`, `shadowOpacity`, etc. ... properties.